# "Network Name Cannot Be Found" for Reachable Host

Tags: windows-xp, network-share, server-message-block

Client:  Windows XP SP3 running under VMWare Fusion 2.0.1 with Bridged Networking under MacOS 10.5.8.

Server:  Windows Server 2008 x64 SP1

I can ping the server, I can RDP to the server.  I can't "net view" the server, or connect to shares on the server, and I get "The network name cannot be found." (Error 67).

I try to access the server via IP address with the same results.

"net view \servername" or "net view \address" returns "Windows cannot find the network path." (Error 51)

I'm only using DNS in my network, not WINS.  Windows Firewall is off.

The server shows many shares in the Server Manager, and everything is accessible from other clients.  I can access shares on the server logged on under my credentials from other hosts (i.e. my Citrix servers).

Basically I can't seem to do SMB sessions from one client to only this server.

From the server to this client, I can't access \clientname\c$ or \clientip\c$.  If I use the client's name, I get Access Denied errors (logged on as Domain Admin on the server).  If I use the IP address, I get "The network path was not found." (Error 53)

Every time the VM reconnects to the work LAN from sleep I get "duplicate name exists on the network" errors but its never been a problem.  This reachability issue for this single host started yesterday.

Ideas?  This is making me a little crazy. ;-)

Comment: Can you access the shares using the FQDN?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have more then one domain. And one of the hosts (server or client) has an account in the domain its not part of anymore. It happens when a host is installed on one domain and moved to another domain. If so, just delete the obsolete account.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you use the servers IP to smb map to network drives?

also might have to use NATting between the client and mac or add to the client xp DNS record the macs ip.

Comment: IP, short hostname, and long hostname all yield the same results.

I'm not sure I understand the second suggestion.  I've had this VM running on my Mac for months now as my primary work OS without problems with bridged networking.  I just changed the networking to NATed instead with the same results (tried short, FQDN, and IP to connect to SMB shares, and I get the same errors I describe above).

This would lead me to believe that the virtualization is not a factor.